# Custom Property Drawers for Generic Classes C# Unity

Tags: c#, generics, properties, unity-game-engine, drawer

I'm having trouble showing a Serializable generic class in the inspector.

The Serializable generic class is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

[Serializable]
public class GenericClass<T> where T : struct
{
    [SerializeField]
    string _serializedString;

    public string SerializedString
    {
        get { return _serializedString; }
        set { _serializedString = value; }
    }

    ... // Functions using the generic type
}
```

The Custom Property Drawer is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(GenericClass<>))]
public class GenericClassDrawer: PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        SerializedProperty stringProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative("SerializedString");

        stringProperty.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(position, stringProperty.stringValue);
    }
}
```

And the MonoBehaviour I'm using the test the generic class is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    enum BasicEnum
    {
        First,
        Second,
        Third,
        Fourth
    }

    [SerializeField]
    GenericClass<BasicEnum> _editorEnum;
}
```

Using this current code the MonoBehaviour TestClass does not display anything in the inspector. It should be showing a text field.

I believe this is due to the generic nature of the class but I've been unable to find examples of anybody using Custom Property Drawers with Generic Classes.

My questions are - Is this possible? What am I missing from the code that would allow the text field to appear as expected? If it's not possible as the code currently is are there any workarounds for property drawers for generic classes?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6):

This won't work because Unity currently (4.x/5.0) does not serialize generic classes. One trick to serialize generics is to inherit from them. So for example in this case you could have:

```
[Serializable]
class GenericClassInt: GenericClass<int> { ... }

[Serializable]
class GenericClassFloat: GenericClass<float> { ... }
```

And then you can have the editor for the fields:

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(GenericClassInt))]
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(GenericClassFloat))]
public class GenericClassDrawer: PropertyDrawer { ... }
```

This is not as elegant as it could be, but solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One work around is to inherit from a non generic abstract base class. This works because property.FindPropertyRelative(...) looks up the value at runtime not compile time so it finds the value in the concrete runtime instance.

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class Generic { }

[Serializable]
public abstract class Generic<T> : Generic {
    public T value;
}
[Serializable]
public class GenericInt : Generic<int> { }
[Serializable]
public class GenericFloat : Generic<float> { }

[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof (Generic), true)]
public class IngredientDrawer : PropertyDrawer {
    public override void OnGUI (Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty (position, label, property);
        position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel (position, GUIUtility.GetControlID (FocusType.Passive), label);
        EditorGUI.PropertyField (position, property.FindPropertyRelative ("value"), GUIContent.none);
        EditorGUI.EndProperty ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code: you are requesting by name SerializedString, which corresponds to a property, and a non-serialized field. Enter this code to receive SerializedProperty:

SerializedProperty stringProperty = property.FindPropertyRelative("_serializedString");

You should be requesting a FIELD, not a property

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely positive, but in my past experience Unity doesn't support CustomPropertyDrawers of Generic classes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If you are right I may need to try some kind of wrapper for it but I'm not sure how that would work either.

Comment: I had a similar problem and I just gave up after a couple of rather unproductive hours. Best of luck!